# JAVA apache-poi: Matching strings in iteration, need to write final values into specific rows

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm working on a code that reads excel files (looking at cells in columns) and then writes something that looks like the following tables:

I have an excel file that looks like this:

```
      col1     col2    col3    col4
      -----------------------------
row1 | 2,3,1    _        1      w
row2 | 3,2,7    _        2      x
row3 |   _      _        3      y
row4 |  4,9     _        4      z
```

I'm writing some values (using Apache POI) in column 2 that look like this:

```
      col1     col2    col3    col4
      -----------------------------
row1 | 2,3,1  x,y,w      1      w
row2 | 3,2,7   y,x       2      x
row3 |   _      _        3      y
row4 |  4,9     z        4      z
```

Essentially, column 3 and column 1 are being compared, and if cell (1,1) has values matched in column 3, column 4's values (which correspond to column 3) are written into column 2.

Here's my code: Important areas are hashed out.

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 50000; rowIndex++) {          
for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 30; columnIndex++) {
                try {
                    XSSFCell COL0 = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(0);
                    String buddy = COL0.getStringCellValue();
                    String[] newton = buddy.split(",");
                    XSSFCell COL1 = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(1);
                    String james = COL1.getStringCellValue();
                    XSSFCell COL2 = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(2);
                    String path1 = COL2.getStringCellValue();

                     //IMPORTANT AREA
                    for (String i : newton) {
                        if (i == james) { 
                        System.out.println(path1); //How do I get this (column 3) to only pull out the cells that correlate to col2 and col1 matches.

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                    }} 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
```

Really new to Java, I'm just confused as to the specific syntax for this problem. Looked through the documentation, but I've been stuck for a while on exactly what I should do. Any advice would really help out. Thank you!

**Edit: 2 sets of columns:**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dhVSYPH.png]

```
//del if necessary - maps keys from col1 to col4 - MAIN CHANGES
public static HashMap<String, String> getColusmnMap(Sheet sheet, int col1, int col4) {
       HashMap<String, String> hashMasp = new HashMap<String, String>();
       for (Row rowie : sheet) {
        String koop = getStringCellValue(rowie.getCell(col1));
        String valeue = getStringCellValue(rowie.getCell(col4));
        if (hashMasp.containsKey(koop)) {
         valeue = hashMasp.get(koop) + valeue;
        }
        hashMasp.put(koop, valeue);
       }
       return hashMasp;
     }







  //del if necessary - Col4 and 5 hashmap - MAIN CHANGES
   HashMap<String, String> columnMapio = getColumnMap(sheet, 4, 5);

   for (Row rowie : sheet) {
    String cell0Valeue = getStringCellValue(rowie.getCell(0));
    String[] koops = cell0Valeue.split(",");
    String cell1Values = "";
    for (String koop : koops) {
     if (columnMapio.containsKey(koop)) {
      cell1Values += columnMapio.get(koop) + ",";
     }
    }
    if (cell1Values.length()>0) cell1Values = cell1Values.substring(0, cell1Values.length() -1);
    System.out.println(cell1Values);
    Cell cell = rowie.getCell(1);
    if (cell != null) {
      cell.setCellValue(cell1Values);
    } else {
      rowie.createCell(1).setCellValue(cell1Values);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we have the following in the first sheet of  `Mappe1.xlsx`:

[image]

Then the following should do what you want:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.util.HashMap;

class ReadAndWriteTest {

 // a method for getting all possible cell values as strings
 public static String getStringCellValue(Cell cell) {
  String result = new String();
  if (cell != null) {
   switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
     result = cell.getStringCellValue();
    break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
     if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
      result = (cell.getDateCellValue()).toString();
     } else {
      if(cell.getNumericCellValue() == (long)cell.getNumericCellValue())
       result = String.format("%s",(long)cell.getNumericCellValue());
      else
       result = String.format("%s",cell.getNumericCellValue());
     }
    break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
     result = new Boolean(cell.getBooleanCellValue()).toString();
    break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
     result = cell.getCellFormula();
    break;
    default:
   }
  }
  return result;    
 }

 // a method for getting a HashMap which maps keys from col1 to values from col2
 public static HashMap<String, String> getColumnMap(Sheet sheet, int col1, int col2) {
   HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    hashMap.put(getStringCellValue(row.getCell(col1)), getStringCellValue(row.getCell(col2)));
   }
   return hashMap;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("Mappe1.xlsx");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   // get a HashMap with keys from column 2 and values from column 3
   HashMap<String, String> columnMap = getColumnMap(sheet, 2, 3);

   for (Row row : sheet) {
    String cell0Value = getStringCellValue(row.getCell(0));
    String[] keys = cell0Value.split(",");
    String cell1Value = "";
    for (String key : keys) {
     if (columnMap.containsKey(key)) {
      cell1Value += columnMap.get(key) + ",";
     }
    }
    if (cell1Value.length()>0) cell1Value = cell1Value.substring(0, cell1Value.length() -1);
    System.out.println(cell1Value);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
    if (cell != null) {
      cell.setCellValue(cell1Value);
    } else {
      row.createCell(1).setCellValue(cell1Value);
    }
   }

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Mappe1.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);

  } catch (InvalidFormatException ifex) {
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

You must go away from the `Python` concepts and bother yourself with the `Java` concepts. In `apache-poi` there is not such a thing like `col_values`. And the cell values are not strings per default. So we must examine them further and having a method for getting all possible cell values as strings.

**Edit:**

A `HashMap` maps keys to values. One advantage is that the keys are unique per definition. So if we add multiple values to the same key, only the last value will be in the map.

If you don't want this, but want to concatenate all values added to the same key, then you have to change the `public static HashMap<String, String> getColumnMap(Sheet sheet, int col1, int col2)`in my example.

```
// a method for getting a HashMap which maps keys from col1 to values from col2
 public static HashMap<String, String> getColumnMap(Sheet sheet, int col1, int col2) {
   HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    String key = getStringCellValue(row.getCell(col1));
    String value = getStringCellValue(row.getCell(col2));
    if (hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
     value = hashMap.get(key) + value;
    }
    hashMap.put(key, value);
   }
   return hashMap;
 }
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect such a detailed response, thank you! 

I'll definitely have to review this code a couple times to really get it. It's been really tough getting away from python, haha. I've only been programming for three months, and I've only started learning java in the last month and it feels totally dissimilar to python. You're absolutely right though, I've been coding this in the python mindset and I definitely need to break away from that. Thank you again!

Comment: Also, quick question.

When I run this program for an excel file where a cell in column 3 is repeated a few times to correspond to multiple cells in col 4, I find that instead of adding all of these values up, the program instead replaces the value printed in column 2 with whatever was the last value matched in column 4.

Essentially, if 1, 1, 1, 1 was repeated for W, X, Y, and Z. With 2, 2, 2, 2, being A, B, C, etc.

What would be printed in the first row of column 2 is just a single Y.

W and X should have also been printed, but I think they were erased as Y is printed.

Comment: Again thank you for all your help. I've been trying to deconstruct your code to see what might be causing this, but I haven't had any good guesses as of yet.

Comment: Sorry man, I got one last question. I edited the question above to contain the changes I made to better visualize this.
Essentially, if the excel file has a second set of columns that also need to be mapped to column 1 (http://i.imgur.com/dhVSYPH.png), would I just have to write some redundant code to cover for those columns as well? In the question above, I added two new hashmaps to account for column 4 and 5. I changed the variables to prevent one hashmap from overwriting another. The code continues to write your maps normally, but disregards mine. Not sure what I missed or if I'm just wrong